# Creating textview using arraylist

Tags: android, uiview, textview

I have requirement to show results. I want to know what is best possible way to achieve it.(Requirement is shown in jpeg file[image]
Can it be a textview inside list adapter or we just textview. The box will be decided dynamically based on some condition. It can be from 0 to many(mostly 2). Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Read this link, It will be helpful, For 2/3 item dynamically, Make 3 items in listview xml and dynamically send null to item which you dont wanna show.

Comment: use customize adapter listview in which you can add any number of textview ,imageview  based on the requirement.